# Side-by-side plots with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, r-faq

I would like to place two plots side by side using the [ggplot2 package](http://crantastic.org/packages/ggplot2), i.e. do the equivalent of `par(mfrow=c(1,2))`.

For example, I would like to have the following two plots show side-by-side with the same scale.

```
x <- rnorm(100)
eps <- rnorm(100,0,.2)
qplot(x,3*x+eps)
qplot(x,2*x+eps)
```

Do I need to put them in the same data.frame?

```
qplot(displ, hwy, data=mpg, facets = . ~ year) + geom_smooth()
```

Comment: I think you might be able to do this with lattice. Is ggplot2 a hard requirement?

Comment: No.  But I had already put in the time tweaking the qplots so it was just the way I liked. :-)  And I'm trying to play around with ggplot.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798162/generating-multiple-plots-in-ggplot-by-factor

Comment: For a nice overview, see the vignette for the [egg package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/): [Laying out multiple plots on a page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html)

Comment: For anything beyond the most basic plot, you should use ggplot instead of qplot

Answer (score 627, accepted):

#### Any ggplots side-by-side (or n plots on a grid)

The function `grid.arrange()` in the [`gridExtra`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/index.html) package will combine multiple plots; this is how you put two side by side.

```
require(gridExtra)
plot1 <- qplot(1)
plot2 <- qplot(1)
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ncol=2)
```

This is useful when the two plots are not based on the same data, for example if you want to plot different variables without using reshape().

This will plot the output as a side effect. To print the side effect to a file, specify a device driver (such as `pdf`, `png`, etc), e.g.

```
pdf("foo.pdf")
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2)
dev.off()
```

or, use `arrangeGrob()` in combination with `ggsave()`,

```
ggsave("foo.pdf", arrangeGrob(plot1, plot2))
```

This is the equivalent of making two distinct plots using `par(mfrow = c(1,2))`. This not only saves time arranging data, it is necessary when you want two dissimilar plots.

---

#### Appendix: Using Facets

Facets are helpful for making similar plots for different groups. This is pointed out below in many answers below, but I want to highlight this approach with examples equivalent to the above plots.

```
mydata <- data.frame(myGroup = c('a', 'b'), myX = c(1,1))

qplot(data = mydata, 
    x = myX, 
    facets = ~myGroup)

ggplot(data = mydata) + 
    geom_bar(aes(myX)) + 
    facet_wrap(~myGroup)
```

---

#### Update

the `plot_grid` function in the [`cowplot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/index.html) is worth checking out as an alternative to `grid.arrange`. See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31223588/199217) by @claus-wilke below and [this vignette](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31223588/199217) for an equivalent approach; but the function allows finer controls on plot location and size, based on [this vignette](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31223588/199217).

Comment: When I ran your code using ggplot objects, sidebysideplot is null. If you want to save the output to a file, use gridArrange. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059099/saving-grid-arrange-plot-to-file

Comment: @Jim thank you for pointing that out. I have revised my answer. Let me know if any questions remain.

Comment: Is grid.aarange depricated now?

Comment: `?grid.arrange` makes me think that this function is now called arrangeGrob. I was able to do what I wanted by doing `a <- arrangeGrob(p1, p2)` and then `print(a)`.

Comment: @blakeoft did you look at the examples? `grid.arrange` is still a valid, non-deprecated function. Did you try to use the function? What happens, if not what you expected.

Comment: @Atticus29 no, it does not appear to be as of 0.9.1, the version on CRAN that was released in 2012. Have you found evidence otherwise?

Comment: @David I tried using it yesterday and got an error. I didn't save the error, but it seems to be a recognized function now. Thanks for replying.

Comment: What if I had 4 plots and wanted `ncol =2` and `nrow = 2` but wanted them arranged by column first before row?

Comment: @Bonono easiest way would be to specify the order of plots within the function, e.g. `grid.arrange(plot1, plot3, plot2, plot4, ncol = 2)`. You can also specify `nrow` but it is not necessary if you have 2 columns and four plots.

Comment: I have 6 plots in two separate lists of 3 and do `do.call(grid.arrange,c(gg_list1,gg_list2 , ncol = 2, nrow  = 3))` but  always fills left to right before top to bottom

Comment: @Bonono try using list elements like `gg_list1[[1]], gg_list1[[3]], ...`

Comment: For those interested: `grid.arrange(grobs = c(gg_list1, gg_list2), ncol = 2, as.table = FALSE)` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877386/grid-arrange-ggplot2-plots-by-columns-instead-of-by-row-using-lists/40877889?noredirect=1#comment68971679_40877889

Comment: I like this solution because it allows me to add axes labels under both/all plots (e.g., `bottom = "Distance (km)"`)

Answer (score 261):

One downside of the solutions based on `grid.arrange` is that they make it difficult to label the plots with letters (A, B, etc.), as most journals require.

I wrote the [cowplot](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/index.html) package to solve this (and a few other) issues, specifically the function `plot_grid()`:

```
library(cowplot)

iris1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() + theme_bw()

iris2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.7) + theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.8))

plot_grid(iris1, iris2, labels = "AUTO")
```

[image]

The object that `plot_grid()` returns is another ggplot2 object, and you can save it with `ggsave()` as usual:

```
p <- plot_grid(iris1, iris2, labels = "AUTO")
ggsave("plot.pdf", p)
```

Alternatively, you can use the cowplot function `save_plot()`, which is a thin wrapper around `ggsave()` that makes it easy to get the correct dimensions for combined plots, e.g.:

```
p <- plot_grid(iris1, iris2, labels = "AUTO")
save_plot("plot.pdf", p, ncol = 2)
```

(The `ncol = 2` argument tells `save_plot()` that there are two plots side-by-side, and `save_plot()` makes the saved image twice as wide.)

For a more in-depth description of how to arrange plots in a grid see [this vignette.](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/plot_grid.html) There is also a vignette explaining how to make plots with a [shared legend.](https://wilkelab.org/cowplot/articles/shared_legends.html)

One frequent point of confusion is that the cowplot package changes the default ggplot2 theme. The package behaves that way because it was originally written for internal lab uses, and we never use the default theme. If this causes problems, you can use one of the following three approaches to work around them:

*1. Set the theme manually for every plot.* I think it's good practice to always specify a particular theme for each plot, just like I did with `+ theme_bw()` in the example above. If you specify a particular theme, the default theme doesn't matter.

*2. Revert the default theme back to the ggplot2 default.* You can do this with one line of code:

```
theme_set(theme_gray())
```

*3. Call cowplot functions without attaching the package.* You can also not call `library(cowplot)` or `require(cowplot)` and instead call cowplot functions by prepending `cowplot::`. E.g., the above example using the ggplot2 default theme would become:

```
## Commented out, we don't call this
# library(cowplot)

iris1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot()

iris2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.7) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.8))

cowplot::plot_grid(iris1, iris2, labels = "AUTO")
```

[image]

**Updates:**

- As of cowplot 1.0, the default ggplot2 theme is not changed anymore.
- As of ggplot2 3.0.0, plots can be labeled directly, see e.g. [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51480611/4975218)

Comment: in the output cowplot is removing the background theme, of the both plots ? is there any alternative ?

Comment: @VAR121 Yes, it's one line of code. Explained at the end of the first section of the introductory vignette: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html

Comment: Is it possible to have the same y scale for all plots with this package?

Comment: You'll have to set the y scales manually to match. Or consider faceting.

Comment: You could set a ggtitle() for each plot before using grid.arrange() though?

Comment: ggplot 3.0.0 now has the option for a *tag*

Comment: Is there a way to specify the panel size using `plot_grid()`? I just tried to use it and it squashes my figures. Maybe I need to specify the ggplot image sizes before using `plot_grid()`?

Comment: why exactly is this vignette always cutting my figures at the top'

Answer (score 95):

Using the [patchwork](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) package, you can simply use `+` operator:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear))


p1 + p2
```

[image: patchwork]

Other operators include `/` to stack plots to place plots side by side, and `()` to group elements. For example you can configure a top row of 3 plots and a bottom row of one plot with `(p1 | p2 | p3) /p`. For more examples, see the [package documentation](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/assembly.html).

Comment: Patchwork is an awesome addition to the graph layout package landscape. Thanks!

Comment: I've used most of these other solutions over the years, and I have to say that this answer (patchwork) is my preferred by far.

Answer (score 53):

You can use the following `multiplot` function from  [Winston Chang's R cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/)

```
multiplot(plot1, plot2, cols=2)
```

---

```
multiplot <- function(..., plotlist=NULL, cols) {
    require(grid)

    # Make a list from the ... arguments and plotlist
    plots <- c(list(...), plotlist)

    numPlots = length(plots)

    # Make the panel
    plotCols = cols                          # Number of columns of plots
    plotRows = ceiling(numPlots/plotCols) # Number of rows needed, calculated from # of cols

    # Set up the page
    grid.newpage()
    pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(plotRows, plotCols)))
    vplayout <- function(x, y)
        viewport(layout.pos.row = x, layout.pos.col = y)

    # Make each plot, in the correct location
    for (i in 1:numPlots) {
        curRow = ceiling(i/plotCols)
        curCol = (i-1) %% plotCols + 1
        print(plots[[i]], vp = vplayout(curRow, curCol ))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 19):

Yes, methinks you need to arrange your data appropriately. One way would be this:

```
X <- data.frame(x=rep(x,2),
                y=c(3*x+eps, 2*x+eps),
                case=rep(c("first","second"), each=100))

qplot(x, y, data=X, facets = . ~ case) + geom_smooth()
```

I am sure there are better tricks in plyr or reshape -- I am still not really up to speed 
on all these powerful packages by Hadley.

Answer (score 17):

Using the reshape package you can do something like this.

```
library(ggplot2)
wide <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100), eps = rnorm(100, 0, .2))
wide$first <- with(wide, 3 * x + eps)
wide$second <- with(wide, 2 * x + eps)
long <- melt(wide, id.vars = c("x", "eps"))
ggplot(long, aes(x = x, y = value)) + geom_smooth() + geom_point() + facet_grid(.~ variable)
```

Answer (score 17):

There is also [multipanelfigure package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multipanelfigure/vignettes/panel-positioning.html) that is worth to mention. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51220506/786542).

```r
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())

q1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_point(aes(mpg, disp))
q2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear))
q3 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_smooth(aes(disp, qsec))
q4 <- ggplot(mtcars) + geom_bar(aes(carb))

library(magrittr)
library(multipanelfigure)
figure1 <- multi_panel_figure(columns = 2, rows = 2, panel_label_type = "none")
# show the layout
figure1
```

[image]

```r
figure1 %<>%
  fill_panel(q1, column = 1, row = 1) %<>%
  fill_panel(q2, column = 2, row = 1) %<>%
  fill_panel(q3, column = 1, row = 2) %<>%
  fill_panel(q4, column = 2, row = 2)
figure1
```

[image]

```r
# complex layout
figure2 <- multi_panel_figure(columns = 3, rows = 3, panel_label_type = "upper-roman")
figure2
```

[image]

```r
figure2 %<>%
  fill_panel(q1, column = 1:2, row = 1) %<>%
  fill_panel(q2, column = 3, row = 1) %<>%
  fill_panel(q3, column = 1, row = 2) %<>%
  fill_panel(q4, column = 2:3, row = 2:3)
figure2
```

[image]

Created on 2018-07-06 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0.9000).

Answer (score 15):

ggplot2 is based on grid graphics, which provide a different system for arranging plots on a page. The `par(mfrow...)` command doesn't have a direct equivalent, as grid objects (called *grobs*) aren't necessarily drawn immediately, but can be stored and manipulated as regular R objects before being converted to a graphical output. This enables greater flexibility than the *draw this now* model of base graphics, but the strategy is necessarily a little different.

I wrote `grid.arrange()` to provide a simple interface as close as possible to `par(mfrow)`. In its simplest form, the code would look like:

```
library(ggplot2)
x <- rnorm(100)
eps <- rnorm(100,0,.2)
p1 <- qplot(x,3*x+eps)
p2 <- qplot(x,2*x+eps)

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

More options are detailed in [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html).

One common complaint is that plots aren't necessarily aligned e.g. when they have axis labels of different size, but this is by design: `grid.arrange` makes no attempt to special-case ggplot2 objects, and treats them equally to other grobs (lattice plots, for instance). It merely places grobs in a rectangular layout.

For the special case of ggplot2 objects, I wrote another function, `ggarrange`, with a similar interface, which attempts to align plot panels (including facetted plots) and tries to respect the aspect ratios when defined by the user.

```
library(egg)
ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```

Both functions are compatible with `ggsave()`. For a general overview of the different options, and some historical context, [this vignette offers additional information](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html).

Answer (score 10):

**Update:** This answer is very old. `gridExtra::grid.arrange()` is now the recommended approach.
I leave this here in case it might be useful.

---

Stephen Turner [posted the `arrange()` function on *Getting Genetics Done* blog](http://gettinggeneticsdone.blogspot.com/2010/03/arrange-multiple-ggplot2-plots-in-same.html) (see post for application instructions)

```
vp.layout <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row=x, layout.pos.col=y)
arrange <- function(..., nrow=NULL, ncol=NULL, as.table=FALSE) {
 dots <- list(...)
 n <- length(dots)
 if(is.null(nrow) & is.null(ncol)) { nrow = floor(n/2) ; ncol = ceiling(n/nrow)}
 if(is.null(nrow)) { nrow = ceiling(n/ncol)}
 if(is.null(ncol)) { ncol = ceiling(n/nrow)}
        ## NOTE see n2mfrow in grDevices for possible alternative
grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout=grid.layout(nrow,ncol) ) )
 ii.p <- 1
 for(ii.row in seq(1, nrow)){
 ii.table.row <- ii.row 
 if(as.table) {ii.table.row <- nrow - ii.table.row + 1}
  for(ii.col in seq(1, ncol)){
   ii.table <- ii.p
   if(ii.p > n) break
   print(dots[[ii.table]], vp=vp.layout(ii.table.row, ii.col))
   ii.p <- ii.p + 1
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: it's basically a very outdated version of `grid.arrange` (wish I hadn't posted it on mailing lists at the time -- there is no way of updating these online resources), the packaged version is a better choice if you ask me

Answer (score 9):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
eps <- rnorm(100,0,.2)
df <- data.frame(x, eps) %>% 
  mutate(p1 = 3*x+eps, p2 = 2*x+eps) %>% 
  tidyr::gather("plot", "value", 3:4) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x , y = value)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_smooth() + 
    facet_wrap(~plot, ncol =2)

df
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Consider also `ggarrange` from the `ggpubr` package. It has many benefits, including options to align axes between plots and to merge common legends into one.

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions may not be efficient if you want to plot multiple ggplot plots using a loop (e.g. as asked here: [Creating multiple plots in ggplot with different Y-axis values using a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38223193/creating-multiple-plots-in-ggplot-with-different-y-axis-values-using-a-loop)), which is a desired step in analyzing the unknown (or large) data-sets (e.g., when you  want to plot Counts of all variables in a data-set).

The code below shows how to do that using the mentioned above 'multiplot()', the source of which is here: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2):

```
plotAllCounts <- function (dt){   
  plots <- list();
  for(i in 1:ncol(dt)) {
    strX = names(dt)[i]
    print(sprintf("%i: strX = %s", i, strX))
    plots[[i]] <- ggplot(dt) + xlab(strX) +
      geom_point(aes_string(strX),stat="count")
  }

  columnsToPlot <- floor(sqrt(ncol(dt)))
  multiplot(plotlist = plots, cols = columnsToPlot)
}
```

Now run the function - to get Counts for all variables printed using ggplot on one page

```
dt = ggplot2::diamonds
plotAllCounts(dt)
```

One things to note is that:
 using  `aes(get(strX))`, which you would normally use in loops when working with `ggplot` , in the above code instead of `aes_string(strX)` will NOT draw the desired plots. Instead, it will plot the last plot many times. I have not figured out why - it may have to do the `aes` and `aes_string` are called in `ggplot`.

Otherwise, hope you'll find the function useful.

Comment: Note that your code grows `plots` objects within `for-loop` which is highly inefficient and not recommended in `R`. Please see these great posts to find out better ways to do it: [Efficient accumulation in R](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2015/07/efficient-accumulation-in-r/), 
[Applying a function over rows of a data frame](https://rpubs.com/wch/200398) & [Row-oriented workflows in R with the tidyverse](https://github.com/jennybc/row-oriented-workflows)

Comment: More efficient way to loop through variables is to use `tidy evaluation` approach which has been available since `ggplot2 v.3.0.0` https://stackoverflow.com/a/52045613/786542

Answer (score 1):

In my experience gridExtra:grid.arrange works perfectly, if you are trying to generate plots in a loop.

Short Code Snippet:

```
gridExtra::grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ncol = 2)
```

** Updating this comment to show how to use `grid.arrange()` within a for loop to generate plots for different factors of a categorical variable.

```
for (bin_i in levels(athlete_clean$BMI_cat)) {

plot_BMI <- athlete_clean %>% filter(BMI_cat == bin_i) %>% group_by(BMI_cat,Team) %>% summarize(count_BMI_team = n()) %>% 
          mutate(percentage_cbmiT = round(count_BMI_team/sum(count_BMI_team) * 100,2)) %>% 
          arrange(-count_BMI_team) %>% top_n(10,count_BMI_team) %>% 
          ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Team,count_BMI_team), y = count_BMI_team, fill = Team)) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
            theme_bw() +
            # facet_wrap(~Medal) +
            labs(title = paste("Top 10 Participating Teams with \n",bin_i," BMI",sep=""), y = "Number of Athletes", 
                 x = paste("Teams - ",bin_i," BMI Category", sep="")) +
            geom_text(aes(label = paste(percentage_cbmiT,"%",sep = "")), 
                      size = 3, check_overlap = T,  position = position_stack(vjust = 0.7) ) +
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 00, vjust = 0.5), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.position = "none") +
            coord_flip()

plot_BMI_Medal <- athlete_clean %>% 
          filter(!is.na(Medal), BMI_cat == bin_i) %>% 
          group_by(BMI_cat,Team) %>% 
          summarize(count_BMI_team = n()) %>% 
          mutate(percentage_cbmiT = round(count_BMI_team/sum(count_BMI_team) * 100,2)) %>% 
          arrange(-count_BMI_team) %>% top_n(10,count_BMI_team) %>% 
          ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Team,count_BMI_team), y = count_BMI_team, fill = Team)) +
            geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
            theme_bw() +
            # facet_wrap(~Medal) +
            labs(title = paste("Top 10 Winning Teams with \n",bin_i," BMI",sep=""), y = "Number of Athletes", 
                 x = paste("Teams - ",bin_i," BMI Category", sep="")) +
            geom_text(aes(label = paste(percentage_cbmiT,"%",sep = "")), 
                      size = 3, check_overlap = T,  position = position_stack(vjust = 0.7) ) +
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 00, vjust = 0.5), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5), legend.position = "none") +
            coord_flip()

gridExtra::grid.arrange(plot_BMI, plot_BMI_Medal, ncol = 2)

}
```

One of the Sample Plots from the above for loop is included below.
The above loop will produce multiple plots for all levels of BMI category.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uflN7.png)

If you wish to see a more comprehensive use of `grid.arrange()` within `for` loops, check out https://rpubs.com/Mayank7j_2020/olympic_data_2000_2016

Comment: How does your answer improve on the baptiste's answer of Dec 2 '17 at 4:20? Your answer seems to be a duplicate. Check out what makes an acceptable answer here [answer]

Comment: I was unable to divide the plot as needed within a loop, and hence the suggestion. 
Initially, I wrote the full snippet of my for loop with its implementation but then decided against it for the time being. Will update the full code in a week or so.

Comment: I tried it to do it using cowplot package in the first place itself but was unsuccessful.
On my quick scan, nobody had mentioned multiple plotting solution within a for loop and hence my comment.

Refer me any comment if I am wrong.

Comment: If the code in your answer included a for loop that would be different.

Comment: I would update it in a week probs here and the whole project on Kaggle. 
Cheers.

Comment: Updated my code chunk. Check out the project at https://rpubs.com/Mayank7j_2020/olympic_data_2000_2016

Comment: @ Mayank: great tutorial on rpubs!

Answer (score -2):

The `cowplot` package gives you a nice way to do this, in a manner that suits publication.

```
x <- rnorm(100)
eps <- rnorm(100,0,.2)
A = qplot(x,3*x+eps, geom = c("point", "smooth"))+theme_gray()
B = qplot(x,2*x+eps, geom = c("point", "smooth"))+theme_gray()
cowplot::plot_grid(A, B, labels = c("A", "B"), align = "v")
```

[image]

Comment: See also the package authors' more detailed answer and rationale  above https://stackoverflow.com/a/31223588/199217