# plotting and loop in R

Tags: r, loops, plot

How would you **write a loop** to make plots for mpg vs cyl and mpg vs vs for each model on a separate plot? Thanks.
PS: This is just an example data set and I have 100s of models so, definitely need a loop.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQNY4.jpg)

[image]

Comment: have u tried ggplot with facet_wrap?..hope that will give u good results.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/52045613/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that is *exactly* what you want to achieve. Is it something like that:

```
data("mtcars")

library(tidyverse)

plots <- mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("model") %>%
  mutate(model = str_extract(model, "^[A-Za-z]+"))  %>%
  gather(key = "feature", value = "value", wt, vs) %>%
  group_by(model) %>%
  do(
    plots = ggplot(., aes(x = mpg, y = value)) +
      geom_point() +
      facet_wrap(~feature, scales = "free_y") +
      ggthemes::theme_few() +
      ggtitle(sprintf("Model: %s", .$model))
  ) %>%
  as.list()

plots <- set_names(plots[["plots"]], plots[["model"]])

plots[["Merc"]]
```

[image]