# ggplot2 plots / results are different within and outside of loop [Bug?]

Tags: r, ggplot2

The my simple case:

Plotting graphs **within** the loop brings different results than plotting it directly **after** the loop

```r
# Initialize
Input <- list(c(3,3,3,3),c(1,1,1,1))
  y <- c()
  x <- c()
  plotlist <- c()
  Answer <- c()

  # create helper grid
  x.grid = c(1:4)
  y.grid = c(1:4)
  helpergrid <- expand.grid(xgrid=x.grid, ygrid=y.grid )

  #- Loop Lists -
  for (m in c(1,2))
  { 

    # # Loop within each list
    # for(j in 1:4)
    # {
    #   y[j] <- Input[[m]][j]
    #   x[j] <- j
    # }

    y[1] <- Input[[m]][1]
    x[1] <- 1
    y[2] <- Input[[m]][2]
    x[2] <- 2
    y[3] <- Input[[m]][3]
    x[3] <- 3
    y[4] <- Input[[m]][4]
    x[4] <- 4

    Points <- data.frame(x, y)

 # Example Plot
    plot = ggplot() + labs(title = paste("Loop m = ",m)) + labs(subtitle = paste("y-values = ",Points$y)) + geom_tile(data = helpergrid, aes(x=xgrid, y=ygrid, fill=1), colour="grey20") + geom_point(data = Points, aes(x=Points$x, y=Points$y), stroke=3, size=5, shape=1, color="white") + theme_minimal()

    # Plot to plotlist
    plotlist[[m]] <- plot

    # --- Plot plotlist within loop ---
    plot(plotlist[[m]])
   }

  # --- Plot plotlist outside of loop ---
 plot(plotlist[[1]])
 plot(plotlist[[2]])
```

Here is an image of the results:
[Plot Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo2UC.png)

as [aaumai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11782513/aaumai) is pointing out that there is a nested loop that might cause the issue for ggplot using static values, however the resulting plot *'is'* showing the correct y-value (y=3) explicitely, but the geom_points are using the wrong values (y=1)...

It makes *absolutely (!)* no sense to me, I am relatively new to R and trying to debug this for hours now - so I hope someone can help me with this !!

**EDIT:** I manually removed the nested loop and updated the example code, but the problem still persists :(

Comment: In R, normally you rarely need nested loops. Take a look at either `lapply` or `map` functions in these examples https://stackoverflow.com/a/55524126/786542 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/50930640/786542 | https://stackoverflow.com/a/52045613/786542

Comment: Thanks Tung, I am aware of these methods, but still ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem arises due to your use of `Points$x` within `aes`. The "tl;dr" is that basically you should never use `$` or `[` or `[[` within `aes`. See [the answer here from baptiste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543340/issue-when-passing-variable-with-dollar-sign-notation-to-aes-in-combinatio).

```r
library(ggplot2)
# Initialize
Input <- list(c(3,3,3,3),c(1,1,1,1))
y <- c()
x <- c()
plotlist <- c()
Answer <- c()

# create helper grid
x.grid = c(1:4)
y.grid = c(1:4)
helpergrid <- expand.grid(xgrid=x.grid, ygrid=y.grid )

#- Loop Lists -
for (m in c(1,2)) { 


  y[1] <- Input[[m]][1]
  x[1] <- 1
  y[2] <- Input[[m]][2]
  x[2] <- 2
  y[3] <- Input[[m]][3]
  x[3] <- 3
  y[4] <- Input[[m]][4]
  x[4] <- 4

  Points <- data.frame(x, y)

  # Example Plot
  plot = ggplot() + labs(title = paste("Loop m = ",m)) + labs(subtitle = paste("y-values = ",force(Points$y))) + 
    geom_tile(data = helpergrid, aes(x=xgrid, y=ygrid, fill=1), colour="grey20") + 
    geom_point(data = Points, aes(x=x, y=y), stroke=3, size=5, shape=1, color="white") + theme_minimal()

  # Plot to plotlist
  plotlist[[m]] <- plot

  # --- Plot plotlist within loop ---
  print(plotlist[[m]])
}

# --- Plot plotlist outside of loop ---
print(plotlist[[1]])
print(plotlist[[2]])
```

I believe the reason this happens is due to [lazy evaluation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html). The data passed into `geom_tile/point` gets stored, but when the plot is printed, it grabs `Points$x` from the current environment. During the loop, this points to the current state of the `Points` data frame, the desired state. After the loop is finished, only the second version of `Points` exists, so when the referenced value from `aes` is evaluated, it grabs the x values from `Points$x` as it exists after the second evaluation of the loop. Hope this is clear, feel free to ask further if not.

To clarify, if you remove `Points$` and just refer to `x` within `aes`, it takes these values from the data.frame as it was passed into the data argument of the `geom` calls.

Comment: Thank you, you [aocall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4747043/aocall) are an angel and saving my day. Also thank you for the explanation and reference!!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, this is because you have a loop within the loop.

The plot within the loop returns plots for changing y values in the Points data (from 1 to 4), whereas the plot outside is only plotting the static values.

Comment: Hm... but nested loops are possible I guess, maybe not for ggplot2?

Is there a workaround, like reassigning or caching the results before exiting the loop?

Comment: Maybe it would help to find the problem if you explained what you're trying to achieve with these plots? It's indeed weird that it places the y points at 1 when the label is at three having both Points$y