# How to pass aes parameters of ggplot to function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2

I am using gapminder and trying to write a simple function showing graphs of `lifeExp` against `gdpPercap`. However, when I put the arguments in the function, the arguments are not recognised.

I have tried several answers, with no results yet.

```
plotting <- function (input, xx, yy){
  library (ggplot2)
  library (gapminder)
  ggplot (input, aes (xx, yy, size = pop, color = country)) + geom_point(show.legend = FALSE) 
}
```

When I run `plotting (gampinder, lifeExp, gdpPercap)` to be used as input, `xx` and `yy`, the result is

> "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'gdpPercap' not found"`

This is where I am stuck and `gdpPercap` is there but not found by the code!
Could you please help.

Answer (score 17):

You need to use [tidy evaluation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/dev/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html) inside `aes()`. Either `.data[[ ]]` or `{{ }}` ([curly curly](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/)) would work. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52045613/786542) and [Tidy evaluation section](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html#tidy-evaluation) in Hadley Wickham's Advanced R book.

```r
library(gapminder)
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)

plotting <- function(input, xx, yy) {
  ggplot(input, aes(.data[[xx]], .data[[yy]], size = pop, color = country)) +
    geom_point(show.legend = FALSE)
}

plotting(gapminder, "lifeExp", "gdpPercap")
```

[image]

```r
plotting2 <- function(input, xx, yy) {
  ggplot(input, aes({{xx}}, {{yy}}, size = pop, color = country)) +
    geom_point(show.legend = FALSE)
}

plotting2(gapminder, lifeExp, gdpPercap)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: @Rassoul if this answer solves your question, kindly accept it by checking the tick next to the up/downvote buttons. This way, Tung gets rep-points and the answer is not labelled as unsolved anymore