# ggplot2: Hand over variable to function (nonstadndard eval)

Tags: r, ggplot2, non-standard-evaluation

I'm trying to write a function in which a grouping variable gets handed over to a ggplot2 expression.

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(x = rep(1:20, 5), y = rnorm(100), 
                 grp1 = c(rep("A", 20), rep("B", 20), rep("C", 20), rep("D", 20), rep("E", 20)),
                 grp2 = c(rep("X", 50), rep("Y", 50)),
                 stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

This works

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y, color = grp1)) +
  geom_line()

print(g)
```

This doesn't work

```
plot_this <- function(mydf, mygroup) {

  g <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x, y, color = mygroup)) +
    geom_line()
}

p <- plot_this(df, grp2)
print(p)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'grp2' not found
```

This doesn't work either (inspired by dplyr)

```
plot_this <- function(mydf, mygroup) {

  mygroup <- enquo(mygroup)

  g <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x, y, color = (!! mygroup))) +
    geom_line()
}

p <- plot_this(df, grp2)
print(p)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'grp2' not found
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58786401/786542

Answer (score 0):

I was missing tidy eval:

```
plot_this <- function(mydf, mygroup) {

  mygroup <- enquo(mygroup)

  g <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x, y, color = {{mygroup}})) +
    geom_line()
}

p <- plot_this(df, grp2)
print(p)
```