# importing dataset with check.names =FALSE gives issues with plotting in ggplot2 loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

Because my headers contain brackets I imported my dataset using `check.names = FALSE`.

```
Homo <- read.table("20200602- Homogenate MI-Athero Millepore R file.txt", header=TRUE,
                     sep="\t", as.is=TRUE, na.strings="#NULL!", comment.char = "", check.names = FALSE)
```

**Here I split the file**

```
Atherohomo <- Homo[Homo$"Model Code" == "MI", ]
```

**Here comes the loop**

```
 for (i in names(Homo)[8:32]){

    ggplot(Atherohomo, aes_string(`Sample`, i)) + 
        geom_boxplot(show.legend = F, fill= c("#3e5fa8","#fc9e23","#2D416D","#d47800"), width = 0.4) + 
        geom_beeswarm(aes(color = `Sample`), size=2)

}
```

Data from `dput(head(Atherohomo))`:

```
Atherohomo <- structure(list(`Plate number` = 43:48, `Mouse ID` = c("16-mi10262-01m", 
"16-mi10262-02m", "16-mi10263-03m", "16-mi10263-04m", "16-mi10323-04m", 
"16-mi10456-01m"), Model = c("MI 4 hours", "MI 4 hours", "MI 4 hours", 
"MI 4 hours", "MI 4 hours", "MI 4 hours"), `Model Code` = c("MI", 
"MI", "MI", "MI", "MI", "MI"), Tissue = c("Homogenate", "Homogenate", 
"Homogenate", "Homogenate", "Homogenate", "Homogenate"), Sample = c("4h riva", 
"4h riva", "4h riva", "4h riva", "4h riva", "4h Ctrl"), `Dilution factor` = c(NA_real_, 
NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_), `x25 (pg/ml)` = c(57.83, 
76.29, 27.75, 18.19, 39.55, 36.69), `x1 (pg/ml)` = c(73.53, 
73.53, 69.86, 67.98, 73.53, 71.7), `x2 (pg/ml)` = c(16.57, 
16.21, 15.14, 17.46, 16.57, 14.78), `x3 (pg/ml)` = c(80.99, 
95.15, 82.43, 84.58, 66.21, 69.22), `x4 (pg/ml)` = c(20, 21.56, 
20, 20, 20, 23.11), `x5 (pg/ml)` = c(3.39, 4.35, 2.24, 2.24, 
3.2, 2.72), `IL-4 (pg/ml)` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `x6 (pg/ml)` = c(5.78, 
5.78, 5.44, 5.1, 5.78, 5.1), `x7 (pg/ml)` = c(33.78, 37.65, 
5.31, 5.49, 12.8, 30.34), `x8 (pg/ml)` = c(36.34, 39.35, 36.34, 
34.33, 36.34, 36.34), `x9 (pg/ml)` = c(253.48, 228.34, 234.74, 
181.11, 247.3, 228.34), `x10 (pg/ml)` = c(43.93, 37.7, 50.19, 
53.33, 38.74, 37.18), `x11 (pg/ml)` = c("33.61", "32.01", 
"34.89", "31.69", "x12 (pg/ml)+T4", "30.42"), `x13 (pg/ml)` = c(56.33, 
58.46, 54.19, 56.33, 52.04, 54.19), `x13 (pg/ml)` = c(34.41, 
36.52, 43.86, 44.9, 40.72, 41.77), `x15 (pg/ml)` = c(286.34, 
272.07, 257.73, 254.13, 272.07, 286.34), `x16 (pg/ml)` = c(3.89, 
3.67, 3.67, 3.45, 3.45, 3.56), `x17 (pg/ml)` = c(18.44, 12.48, 
3.72, 2.51, 10.14, 17.88), `x18 (pg/ml)` = c(470.3, 418.68, 25.47, 
17.69, 142.12, 288.25), `x19 (pg/ml)` = c(219.64, 117.09, 65.48, 
59.69, 98.91, 160.71), `x20 (pg/ml)` = c(188.93, 193.6, 181.74, 
179.28, 184.16, 174.29), `x21 (pg/ml)` = c(103.52, 106.61, 
99.71, 98.41, 106, 98.41), `x22 (pg/ml)` = c(204.41, 181.82, 
175.72, 175.72, 181.82, 175.72), `x23 (pg/ml)` = c(13.98, 
14.28, 12.94, 12.79, 13.24, 12.79), `x24 (pg/ml)` = c(15.27, 
13.86, 13.14, 12.41, 13.86, 13.14)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. E.g. provide `dput(head(Atherohomo))`, or a snippet from the raw data file.

Comment: I don't see any weird column names with brackets, nor do you show a loop... is `i` a column name? Or is it a variable with a column name as a string? Have a look at [How to loop over columns in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4856849/903061) - switching to `aes_string` or using `rlang` for your looping variable might solve the problem, but very hard to tell without more info.

Comment: @GregorThomas, I provided more information. Hope this helps.

Comment: With the additional context, I'd suggest [How to loop over columns in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4856849/903061) as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You have a range of issues. You have the x13 column twice. The x11 column has both numbers and text. For the issue with parentheses, you do need to paste the backticks in to get `aes_string` to work. This works for me:

```
Atherohomo2 <- Atherohomo
Atherohomo2$`x13 (pg/ml)` <- NULL
Atherohomo2$`x11 (pg/ml)` <- NULL

for (i in names(Atherohomo2)[8:30]){
  p <- ggplot(Atherohomo2, aes_string('Sample', paste0('`', i, '`'))) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(fill = Sample), show.legend = F, width = 0.4) + 
    # I don't have that package installed:
    # geom_beeswarm(aes(color = `Sample`), size=2) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#3e5fa8","#fc9e23","#2D416D","#d47800"))
  print(p)
}
```