# Plots using loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I am trying to create plots, using a for loop and assigning them in my global envirnoment, as follows:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

datasets::anscombe
#>    x1 x2 x3 x4    y1   y2    y3    y4
#> 1  10 10 10  8  8.04 9.14  7.46  6.58
#> 2   8  8  8  8  6.95 8.14  6.77  5.76
#> 3  13 13 13  8  7.58 8.74 12.74  7.71
#> 4   9  9  9  8  8.81 8.77  7.11  8.84
#> 5  11 11 11  8  8.33 9.26  7.81  8.47
#> 6  14 14 14  8  9.96 8.10  8.84  7.04
#> 7   6  6  6  8  7.24 6.13  6.08  5.25
#> 8   4  4  4 19  4.26 3.10  5.39 12.50
#> 9  12 12 12  8 10.84 9.13  8.15  5.56
#> 10  7  7  7  8  4.82 7.26  6.42  7.91
#> 11  5  5  5  8  5.68 4.74  5.73  6.89


for(i in 1:4){
  var = paste0('p', as.character(i))
  assign(
    x = var,
    value = (ggplot(anscombe, 
                   aes(x=get(paste0('x', as.character(i))), 
                       y=get(paste0('y', as.character(i))))) + geom_point()),
    envir=.GlobalEnv
  )
}

(p1 + p2)/(p3 + p4)
```

[image]

As you can see, all the plots produced are same. But when I use the above same code without for loops, I get intended plots for example: p1 and p3 are shown below.

```r
p1 = ggplot(anscombe, aes(x=get(paste0('x', as.character(1))),
                          y=get(paste0('y', as.character(1))))) + geom_point() 

p3 = ggplot(anscombe, aes(x=get(paste0('x', as.character(3))),
                     y=get(paste0('y', as.character(3))))) + geom_point() 
p1 + p3
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

My question is why isn't the for loop working? Why it's producing the p4 plot for all in the `for` loop?

Comment: These might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50929344/multiple-plots-in-for-loop-ignoring-par & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856849/looping-over-variables-in-ggplot/52045613#52045613

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make this a bit simpler by creating column names and passing them to ggplot, then selectively unquoting them with `!!`

Note that you're already in the global environment so `assign` doesn't need the `envir` argument.

```r
for(i in 1:4) {
  var = paste0('p', i)
  x <- as.name(paste0("x", i))
  y <- as.name(paste0("y", i))
  assign(x = var, value = ggplot(anscombe, aes(!!x, !!y)) + geom_point())
}

(p1 + p2)/(p3 + p4)
```

[image]

Incidentally, you could be even more succinct *and* avoid writing multiple objects to the global environment if you kept all the plots in a list:

```r
p <- lapply(1:4, function(i) {
  ggplot(anscombe, aes(!!as.name(paste0("x", i)), !!as.name(paste0("y", i)))) + 
    geom_point()
})

(p[[1]] + p[[2]])/(p[[3]] + p[[4]])
```

Comment: I tried a similar way, but using `eval(as.name(paste0('x', i)))`, but again got the same plot for all section. Does it matter if I define column names inside `aes` or outside `ggplot` call?

Comment: @monte `ggplot2` uses non-standard evaluation, so if you want to create names on the fly like this, you you need to pass them as names and unquote them with `!!`. If you use `get` or `eval` you are passing the whole column as data, not the symbolic name of the column, which is what ggplot wants.

Comment: Thanks Allan, using `!!` does work, but I am just wondering why does `eval` and `get` works when used individually for each plot, but in `for` loop every previous plot gets overwritten by the last plot.