# R Function that graphs with modified column name

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the code on it's own that works.

```
ggplot(stkPres, aes(x = AAPL, y = AAPL.ret)) + geom_point()
```

Here is my attempt at a function:

```
graphic.stock.vs.return <- function(abbrev) {
  ggplot(stkPres, aes(x = abbrev, y = abbrev.ret)) + geom_point()
 
}
```

graphic.stock.vs.return(AAPL) would graph the exact same way as ggplot(stkPres, aes(x = AAPL, y = AAPL.ret)) + geom_point().

What do I need to do to my function for it to work properly?

Comment: Please provide a full example including test input.  See instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag home page.

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for `aes_string(x = abbrev, y = paste0(abbrev, ".ret"))`.

Comment: These might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309285/how-to-use-a-variable-to-specify-column-name-in-ggplot/55524126#55524126 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856849/looping-over-variables-in-ggplot/52045613#52045613

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to pass value in an unquoted way you could do :

```
library(ggplot2)

graphic.stock.vs.return <- function(abbrev) {

  abbr <- deparse(substitute(abbrev))
  ggplot(stkPres, aes(x = .data[[abbr]],
                      y = .data[[paste0(abbr, '.ret')]])) + geom_point()
}

graphic.stock.vs.return(AAPL)
```

If you are going to pass variable as string.

```
graphic.stock.vs.return <- function(abbr) {
  ggplot(stkPres, aes(x = .data[[abbr]], 
                      y = .data[[paste0(abbr, '.ret')]])) + geom_point()
}

graphic.stock.vs.return("AAPL")
```