# ggplot2 adding stacked barchart to heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, heatmap

I would like to add functional information to a HeatMap (geom_tile). I've got the following simplified DataFrame and R code producing a HeatMap and a separate stacked BarPlot (in the right order, corresponding to the HeatMap).

**Question:** 
How can I add the BarPlot to the right edge/side of the Heatmap?? It shouldn't overlap with any of the tiles, and the tiles of the BarPlot should align with the tiles of the HeatMap.

**Data:**

```
AccessionNumber <- c('A4PU48','A9YWS0','B7FKR5','G4W9I5','B7FGU7','B7FIR4','DY615543_2','G7I6Q7','G7I9C1','G7I9Z0','A4PU48','A9YWS0','B7FKR5','G4W9I5','B7FGU7','B7FIR4','DY615543_2','G7I6Q7','G7I9C1','G7I9Z0','A4PU48','A9YWS0','B7FKR5','G4W9I5','B7FGU7','B7FIR4','DY615543_2','G7I6Q7','G7I9C1','G7I9Z0','A4PU48','A9YWS0','B7FKR5','G4W9I5','B7FGU7','B7FIR4','DY615543_2','G7I6Q7','G7I9C1','G7I9Z0')
Bincode <- c(13,25,29,19,1,1,35,16,4,1,13,25,29,19,1,1,35,16,4,1,13,25,29,19,1,1,35,16,4,1,13,25,29,19,1,1,35,16,4,1)
MMName <- c('amino acid metabolism','C1-metabolism','protein','tetrapyrrole synthesis','PS','PS','not assigned','secondary metabolism','glycolysis','PS','amino acid metabolism','C1-metabolism','protein','tetrapyrrole synthesis','PS','PS','not assigned','secondary metabolism','glycolysis','PS','amino acid metabolism','C1-metabolism','protein','tetrapyrrole synthesis','PS','PS','not assigned','secondary metabolism','glycolysis','PS','amino acid metabolism','C1-metabolism','protein','tetrapyrrole synthesis','PS','PS','not assigned','secondary metabolism','glycolysis','PS')
cluster <- c(1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4)
variable <- c('rd2c_24','rd2c_24','rd2c_24','rd2c_24','rd2c_24','rd2c_24','rd2c_24','rd2c_24','rd2c_24','rd2c_24','rd2c_48','rd2c_48','rd2c_48','rd2c_48','rd2c_48','rd2c_48','rd2c_48','rd2c_48','rd2c_48','rd2c_48','rd2c_72','rd2c_72','rd2c_72','rd2c_72','rd2c_72','rd2c_72','rd2c_72','rd2c_72','rd2c_72','rd2c_72','rd2c_96','rd2c_96','rd2c_96','rd2c_96','rd2c_96','rd2c_96','rd2c_96','rd2c_96','rd2c_96','rd2c_96')
value <- c(2.15724042939,1.48366099919,1.29388509992,1.59969471112,1.82681962192,2.13347487296,1.08298157478,1.20709456306,1.02011775131,0.88018823632,1.41435923375,1.31680079684,1.32041325076,1.23402873856,2.04977975574,1.90651971106,0.911615352178,1.05021352328,1.18437303394,1.05620421143,1.02132613918,1.22080237755,1.40759491365,1.43131574695,1.65848581311,1.91886008221,0.639581269674,1.11779720968,1.09406554542,1.02259316617,1.00529867534,1.30885290475,1.39376458384,1.35503544429,1.81418617518,1.92505106722,0.862870707741,1.0832577668,1.03118887309,1.21310404226)
df <- data.frame(AccessionNumber, Bincode, MMName, cluster, variable, value)
```

**HeatMap plot:**

```
hm <- ggplot(df, aes(x=variable, y=AccessionNumber))
hm + geom_tile(aes(fill=value), colour = 'white') + scale_fill_gradient2(low='blue', midpoint=1, high='red')
```

**stacked BarPlot:**

```
bp <- ggplot(df, aes(x=sum(df$Bincode), fill=MMName))
bp + stat_bin(aes(ymax = ..count..), binwidth = 1, geom='bar')
```

Thank you very much for your help/support!!

[image: HeatMap]

[image: BarPlot]

The variables of the y-axis are sorted first by increasing "cluster" then alphabetically by "AccessionNumber". This is true for both the HeatMap as well as the BarPlot. The values appear in the same order in both plots, but show two different variables (same amount of rows and in the same order, but different content). The HeatMap displays a continuous variable in contrast to the BarPlot which displays a categorical variable. Therefore, the plots could be combined, displaying additional information.

Please help!

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24147500/r-heatmap-type-plot-with-frequency-plot/24148288#24148288) can help

Comment: maybe [this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24189239/471093)

Comment: It looks like you are visualizing different variables in each of the two plots -- if so, what do you mean when you say you want the tiles to line up?

Comment: @mmk: The BarPlot should simply extend the HeatMap as the fifth column. Both plots have 10 rows and consist of tiles. The 10 rows of the HeatMap should align with the 10 rows of the BarPlot. The combined plot I want, would display values of the same AccessionNumber in each row.

Comment: @tryptofame Perhaps I misunderstand you -- looking at your second chart, I see only 8 "rows" that are layers of variable width and could never align with the discrete y axis rows in your first chart.

Comment: @mmk: yes and no :) only 8 categories --> colours, but 10 tiles high. "PS" appears 3 times (1 colour but 3 rows high). if looking at the height of each tile you should be able to count 10 rows. Delineation would help of course.