# par(mfrow) in R for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this code:

```
plotfn= function(u) {
  flt = filter(d, utensil ==u)
  ggplot(flt,aes(x=p)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.5, position= position_dodge(0.5), color="black",fill="cadetblue4")+ ggtitle("Histogram of P")+labs( x="P", y="Number of Observations")
}
lapply(unique(d$utensil),plotfn)
```

I tried doing a `par(mfrow= c(3,3))` to get all 9 plots in 1 screen but it doesn't work. I have to use ggplot.

Comment: Useful: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/ (see the "Facets" chapter)

Comment: Also, this question may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226807/multiple-graphs-in-one-canvas-using-ggplot2

Comment: Why not use `facet_grid`? The Ggplot system is designed to avoid this sort of messing around. You might wan `grid.arrange` for two different types of plot but not for all 9 of the same type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the `gridExtra` package, which integrates nicely with `ggplot2` and allows you to place multiple plots onto a single page: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gridExtra/vignettes/arrangeGrob.html

To use it, store the output of your `ggplot` calls to a variable, then pass that variable to `grid.arrange`:

```
myGrobs <- lapply(unique(d$utensil),plotfn)
gridExtra::grid.arrange( grobs = myGrobs, nrow = 3 )
```

Answer (score 10):

This should get you started:

```
install.packages("gridExtra")
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, ..., ncol=3, nrow = 3)
```