# Saving grid.arrange() plot (with different heights)

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

Using `df` ([you can download it from here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/38dsmmxhbrupyi5/df_rain_flow.csv?dl=0)), and the code below

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

df <- read.csv("df_rain_flow.csv") 
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d") 

g.top <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = Rain, ymin=0, ymax=Rain)) +
  geom_linerange(size = 0.2, color = "#3399FF", alpha =0.3) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(170,0), expand=c(0,0), trans="reverse")+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(y = "Rain (mm)")+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(5,5,-32,6),units="points"),
        axis.title.y= element_text(color="black", size = 10, vjust = 0.3),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size = 8))

g.bottom <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Date, y = Flow)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.06, color = "blue") +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("1993-01-01"), 
                            as.Date("2016-12-01"), by="1 year"), 
               labels = date_format("%Y"))+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x = "", 
       y = expression(Flow~~(m^{3}~s^{-1})))+
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,5,1,1),units="points"),  
        axis.title.x = element_text(color="black", face="bold", size = 10, margin=margin(10,0,0,0)),
        axis.title.y= element_text(color="black", face="bold", size = 12 ),
        strip.text = element_text(color="black", size= 8, face="bold"),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle=35,vjust=1, hjust=1,size = 8),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size = 8, face="bold"))

grid.arrange(g.top,g.bottom, heights = c(1/5, 4/5))
```

I got this plot (I exported it using Rstudio > export > Save as Image)

[image]

I checked [several questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059099/saving-grid-arrange-plot-to-file) about how to save `grid.arrange()` plot but none of them is similar to my question where the top plot is 1/5 and the bottom plot is 4/5 of total height of the final plot.

I tried the code below

```
g <- arrangeGrob(g.top, g.bottom)
ggsave("plot.png", g, height = 5.2, width = 9.6, dpi = 600)
```

The result is shown below. As expected each plot `g.top` and `g.bottom` represents 50% of the height of the final plot `g`

[image]

Any suggestions how to export the `grid.arrange()` plots with different heights in the final plot?

Comment: @baptiste
Many thanks for your time and help. It worked fine with me. Could you please add it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arrangeGrob` is the twin sister of `grid.arrange` that doesn't draw. You can give it the same arguments and ggsave it,

```
g <- arrangeGrob(g.top, g.bottom, heights = c(1/5, 4/5))
ggsave("plot.png", g, height = 5.2, width = 9.6, dpi = 600)
```

Note that the two plots may be somewhat misaligned, if the y axes are different. For better results, you could use gtable functions, e.g. via the experimental `egg` package:

```
#devtools::install_github("baptiste/egg")
library(egg)
library(grid)
ggarrange(g.top, g.bottom, heights = c(1/5, 4/5))
```