# Increase Resolution of GGPlot graphs to PDF

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, resolution

I have the following code but my ggplot images (UK1,UK2 etc) loose their resolution when saving to the PDF. Is there anyway I can keep the resolution high? I would need the output saved in a PDF (with the 3 UK graphs on the first page, 3 EUR graphs on second and 3 GLB graphs on the third).

```
pdf("J:/GROUPS/Team/20170812.pdf",width=26,height=18,pointsize=10)
grid.arrange(UK1, UK2, UK3)
grid.arrange(EUR1, EUR2, EUR3)
grid.arrange(GLB1, GLB2, GLB3)

dev.off()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059099/saving-grid-arrange-plot-to-file and `dpi` parameter in `ggsave()`