# Unexpected output when arranging ternary plot with ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, gridextra

I'm trying to arrange (via `grid.arrange` in `gridExtra`) a ternary plot from `ggtern`-package and a regular `ggplot2` plot side-by-side. However,  the aesthetics and label positions of the ternary plot are removed.

I'm [aware that this seems to be a bug.](https://github.com/nicholasehamilton/ggtern/issues/16) Any pointers to circumvent this issue and produce the output I'm looking for is much appreciated.

A reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtern)
library(reshape2)
library(gridExtra)

# Some faux data
dat <- replicate(3, runif(5))
dat <- as.data.frame(dat/rowSums(dat))
colnames(dat) <- LETTERS[seq_len(ncol(dat)) + 23]
dat$var <- factor(LETTERS[seq_len(nrow(dat))])

# Make a ternary plot
tern.plot <- 
  ggplot(data = dat, aes(y=Y, x=X, z=Z, color = var, fill = var)) +
  coord_tern() +
  geom_point(size = 3)

# Make a stacked barplot
dat.melt <- melt(dat, id.vars = "var", variable.name = "dim")  
stacked.plot <-
  ggplot(data = dat.melt, aes(x = var, y = value, fill = dim)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

# Arrange the two plots:
grid.arrange(tern.plot, stacked.plot, ncol = 2)
#Warning messages:
#1: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
#2: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
# ...
#9: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

[image: grid.arrange]

The ternary plot should look like:

```
print(tern.plot)
```

[image: tern.plot]

Comment: Try [multiplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249548/side-by-side-plots-with-ggplot2-in-r/8391998#8391998), I've tested it on your plots and it worked perfectly

Comment: the problem is arguably with ggtern, it defines a new `ggplot_build`, but not `ggplotGrob`, so that function is taken from ggplot2 with its own `ggplot_build`

Comment: multiplot doesn't have the same problem because it restricts the input to ggplots, not general grobs, and draws them using a print method redefined in ggtern. I would argue that it would be cleaner to use different function names in ggtern, rather than override them with new, sometimes incompatible functionality.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks! Can you write it as an answer and I'll choose it for posterity. It seems that `ggtern.multi` also does the trick.

Comment: @AEBilgrau, I don't think that copy pasting someone elses answer is considered an answer :) This is why I've put it comments in the first place... Thus I think you should select your own answer as it could be useful for others who haven't heard of `ggtern.multi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the wanted result using `ggtern.multi` which I apparently had completely missed.

```
ggtern.multi(tern.plot, stacked.plot, cols = 2)
```

[image: Wanted result]

As suggested in the comments by David Arenburg, the `multiplot` function also works perfectly.

```
library(devtools)
source_gist("https://gist.github.com/AEBilgrau/2a78a9ebda2226b6b988")
multiplot(tern.plot, stacked.plot, cols = 2)
```