# ggplot draw multiple plots by levels of a variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, histogram, data-visualization

I have a sample dataset

```
d=data.frame(n=rep(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3),2),group=rep(c("A","B"),each=20),stringsAsFactors = F)
```

And I want to draw two separate histograms based on group variable.

I tried this method suggested by @jenesaisquoi in a separate post here
[Generating Multiple Plots in ggplot by Factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798162/generating-multiple-plots-in-ggplot-by-factor/31799540#31799540)

```
ggplot(data=d)+geom_histogram(aes(x=n,y=..count../sum(..count..)),binwidth = 1)+facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image: Histogram output]

It did the trick but if you look closely, the proportions are wrong. It didn't calculate the proportion for each group but rather a grand proportion. I want the proportion to be 0.6 for number 1 for each group, not 0.3.

Then I tried dplyr package, and it didn't even create two graphs. It ignored the `group_by` command. Except the proportion is right this time.

```
d%>%group_by(group)%>%ggplot(data=.)+geom_histogram(aes(x=n,y=..count../sum(..count..)),binwidth = 1)
```

[image: dplyr output]

Finally I tried factoring with `color`

```
ggplot(data=d)+geom_histogram(aes(x=n,y=..count../sum(..count..),color=group),binwidth = 1)
```

But the result is far from ideal. I was going to accept one output but with the bins side by side, not on top of each other.

[image: color=group output]

In conclusion, I want to draw two separate histograms with correct proportions calculated within each group. If there is no easy way to do this, I can live with one graph but having the bins side by side, and with correct proportions for each group. In this example, number 1 should have 0.6 as its proportion.

Comment: `ggplot` won't make separate plots for each group after `group_by`; if you needed entirely separate plots, you'd do something like a combination of `split` and `map`. But that would also be more complicated than it's probably worth. @Luis Paulo Jorge's answer is a good & straightforward way to go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing `..count../sum(..count..)` to `..density..`, it gives you the desired proportion

```
ggplot(data=d) + geom_histogram(aes(x=n, y=..density..), binwidth = 1) + facet_wrap(~group)
```

Comment: nice! you are top

Answer (score 0):

You actually have the separation of charts by variable correct! Especially with ggplot, you sometimes need to consider the scales of the graph separately from the shape. `Facet_wrap` applies a new layer to your data, regardless of scale. It will behave the same, no matter what your axes are. You could also try adding `scale_y_log10()` as a layer, and you'll notice that the overall shape and style of your graph is the same, you've just changed the axes.

What you actually need is a fix to your scales. Understandable - frequency plots can be confusing. `..count../sum(..count..))` treats each bin as an independent unit, regardless of its value. See a good explanation of this here: [Show % instead of counts in charts of categorical variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/show-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables)

What you want is `..density..`, which is basically the count divided by the total count. The difference is subtle in principle, but the important bit is that the value on the x-axis matters. For an extreme case of this, see here: [Normalizing y-axis in histograms in R ggplot to proportion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766856/normalizing-y-axis-in-histograms-in-r-ggplot-to-proportion), where tiny x-axis values produced huge densities.

**Your original code will still work**, just substituting the aesthetics I described above.

`ggplot(data=d)+geom_histogram(aes(x=n,y=..density..,)binwidth = 1)+facet_wrap(~group)`

If you're still confused about density, so are lots of people. Hadley Wickham wrote a long piece about it, you can find that here: http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/density-estimation.pdf