# How to use ggplot to create facets with two factors?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do a plot with facets with some data from a previous model. As a simple example:

```
t=1:10;
x1=t^2;
x2=sqrt(t);
y1=sin(t);
y2=cos(t);
```

How can I plot this data in a 2x2 grid, being the rows one factor (levels `x` and `y`, plotted with different colors) and the columns another factor (levels `1` and `2`, plotted with different linetypes)?

Note: `t` is the common variable for the X axis of all subplots.

Comment: you can use `dput(head(dataset))`, to create a small sample of your dataset. If you wish you can add it here as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating Multiple Plots in ggplot by Factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31798162/generating-multiple-plots-in-ggplot-by-factor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ggplot will be more helpful if the data can be first put into [tidy form](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html). `df` is your data, `df_tidy` is that data in tidy form, where the series is identified in one column that can be mapped in `ggplot` -- in this case to the facet.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  t=1:10,
  x1=t^2,
  x2=sqrt(t),
  y1=sin(t),
  y2=cos(t),
)

df_tidy <- df %>%
  gather(series, value, -t)

ggplot(df_tidy, aes(t, value)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~series, scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! That is exactly what I was looking for!