# How to arrange and label Plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid

I am making a figure for the publication. All my plots were plotted using ggplot in R. Now I want to arrange them into one figure. I am using `gridExtra` package like this but I want to directly arrange along with labels such as A),B) etc..

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

c <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl),mpg))

P1 <- c + geom_boxplot()
P2 <- c +  geom_point()

grid.arrange(P1,P2)
```

Resultant plot

[image]

But I want to label the plots as A. B. like this

[image]

Is there a way to do this??

Comment: See answer by @Claus Wilke to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249548/side-by-side-plots-with-ggplot2) question

Comment: @DidzisElferts Thank you :-)

Comment: @DidzisElferts close as dupe?

Comment: @zx8754 Question itself is not duplicate. Anyone searching with this problem might not get to that question (like me).

Comment: @koundy That’s what “close as duplicate” solves: it places a link to the other question prominently above your description.

Comment: okay got it. Thanks.