# Side by side graph and local image in knitr

Tags: r, latex, png, knitr

I'm trying to include a graph and a local PNG side by side in a knitr LaTeX document, but the PNG ends up on top of the graph. Take this .Rnw example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

<<makeplot, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, include=FALSE>>=
opts_chunk$set(echo=FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, cache = FALSE, error = FALSE)

library("ggplot2")
library("png")
library("grid")
data = data.frame(x = c(1:5), y = c(1:5))
myplot = ggplot(data = data) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))

@

<<these_plots, echo = FALSE, fig.height = 3, fig.width = 8, results = "asis", fig.show = "hold">>==
par(mar=c(4,4,.1,.1),cex.lab=.95,cex.axis=.9,mgp=c(2,.7,0),tcl=-.3)
myplot
grid.raster(readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png")), height = .3, width = .3)
@
```

Which generates this:

[image]

How can I make them side by side? I've also tried the `multiplot()` function from [here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/) but the PNG wouldn't budge from the row above the graph, even when cols was specified as 2.

```
multiplot(myplot,
grid.raster(readPNG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.png", package="png")), height = .3, width = .3), cols = 2)
```

Comment: I would think the mfrow parameter should achieve this for you. See potential duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249548/side-by-side-plots-with-ggplot2

Comment: I have no issue putting two plots side by side... it's when one of them is a local PNG that the behavior is different. These are different questions-- so hopefully this doesn't get closed as a duplicate! Thanks though!

Comment: Any luck with the `mfrow` parameter and plotting the local PNG?

Comment: @Badger Nope, ```par(mfrow = c(1, 2))``` didn't do anything. I think the issue is something to do with grid.raster, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Interesting. Try `grid.newpage()` prior to grid.raster. Looks like it may invoke a new plot as `grid.raster` is dumping into the open "x11" suite.

Comment: That does keep them from overlapping, but they're still not side by side. Progress though!

Comment: Check out plotting an empty plot, that may achieve your result. I just left my machine otherwise I would link it!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have saved your .png image (and called it "Rimage"), something like this should array the .png on the left and the plot ("myplot") on the right of it, each taking up about half the width of your page.

```
\begin{figure}[ht]      
\begin{minipage}[c]{.49\linewidth}                 
\includegraphics[width = 1\linewidth]{Rimage}   
\caption{R image}
\label{Rimage}
\end{minipage}
% \quad                                       
\begin{minipage}[c]{.49\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width = 1\linewidth]{myplot}
\caption{myplot}          
\label{myplot}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```