# How to pass column index inside R loop in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to plot the histogram for all the variables for the Wage dataset in order to understand their distribution. This I  am trying to achieve by passing i column index as parameter inside a for loop in R, using following code.

```
library(ISLR); 
library(ggplot2);
# load wage data
data(Wage)
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
for(i in 1:9){
  ggplot(data=Wage)+geom_bar(aes(x=Wage[,i]))
}
```

But I am unable to produce any plot (this is error free). It is working if I individually provide the column numbers. I suspect the problem is somewhere in the par() or the for line. Kindly requesting to suggest.

Comment: Try `aes_string(x = names(Wage)[i])`

Comment: Oh `aes_string(x = names(Wage)[i])` didn't work

Comment: It works fine, you just have other issues as well. `par` works for base graphics, not `ggplot`, and you need to explicitly `print` ggplots inside loops. See [Side-by-side plots with ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1249548/903061) for fixing the par issue. If you want to see it work without that, delete the `par` line and put `print(ggplot(data=Wage)+geom_bar(aes_string(x=names(Wage)[i])))` in the loop.