# How to converge two plots into one plot (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, linegraph

I have two plots with different x-axis but same y-axis. The order of each x-axis has to be stay in that way. I want to converge two graphs into one, by having one x-axis on bottom and one on top.

[image: plot1]
[image: plot2]

```
plot1 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = Target1, y = RT1)) + geom_point() + geom_line(aes(group = 1)) 
plot2 <- ggplot(df2, aes(x = Target2, y = RT2)) + geom_point() + geom_line(aes(group = 1))
```

How can I get the plot I want?

Comment: Please read [how to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Hence, post some data and specify desired output: do you want both plots to be in one (not realistic, since you want different order of x-axis) or do you want to have the two in one plot (side-by-side)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Side-by-side plots with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249548/side-by-side-plots-with-ggplot2)

Comment: `library(tidyverse); bind_rows(set_names(df1, ~gsub('\\d', '', .x)), set_names(df2, ~gsub('\\d', '', .x)), .id = 'id') %>% ggplot(aes(Target, RT)) + geom_point() + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~id)` ...or something like that

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use sec_axis(). Here I have created two data frames. Both y-axis (RT1 and RT2) are on the same scale. Target1 and Target2 are on different scales.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Target1 = c(1,2,3), RT1 = c(1,2,3))
df2 <- data.frame(Target2 = c(20,30,40), RT2 = c(3,4,5))
```

To demonstrate the effect, I'm using scatter plot for df1 and line plot for df2. I also divide Target2 by 10 to bring the x variables closer and easier to be compared.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df1, mapping = aes(Target1, RT1)) +
  geom_line(data = df2, mapping = aes(Target2/10, RT2)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Target 1", sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*10, name = "Target 2"))
```

[image: Plot 1]

or, if you don't want to rescsale the x-axis, you can use dup_axis() instead.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df1, mapping = aes(Target1, RT1)) +
  geom_line(data = df2, mapping = aes(Target2, RT2)) +
  scale_x_continuous("Target 1", sec.axis = dup_axis(name = "Target 2"))
```

[image: Plot 2]

Hope it helps.