# Saving a image with 2 charts in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, charts

I have a dataset where I want to plot Y and log(Y) against the same X axis , is there any way to have the two charts y ~ X , log(y) ~ X in the same image side by side so that I can compare them.

Sample dataset

```
datastart <- data.frame(x=rep(1:5,2),
    y=c(1,2,10,50,1, .1,9,8,20,19),
    type=rep(c(‘a’,’b’),each=5))
```

Comment: take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249548/side-by-side-plots-with-ggplot2

Comment: Both `facet_xxxx` and `grid.arrange` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(datastart,aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(datastart,aes(x,log(y))) + geom_point()

png(filename="datastart.png")
grid.arrange(p1,p2,ncol=2)
dev.off()
```

Comment: oh cool,  can I save this grid to an image png or pdf?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to do this, I edited the answer to include one option.