# Make scatter (or X, Y) plot by treatment for different time period

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, lattice

**I have a data (R dataframe) like this:**

```
Treatment   Diameter(inches).Sep    Diameter(inches).Dec
Aux_Drop    NA  NA
Aux_Spray    3.7    2
DMSO    NA  NA
Water   4.2 2
Aux_Drop    2.6 3
Aux_Spray    3.7    3
DMSO    4   2
Water   5.2 1
Aux_Drop    5.4 2
Aux_Spray    3.4    2
DMSO    4.8 2
Water   4.2 2
Aux_Drop    4.7 2
Aux_Spray    2.7    2
DMSO    3.4 2
Water   4.9 2
.......
.......
```

I want to make a scatter (or x, y) plot of `diameter` for each `treatment` group. I have found `lattice` library plot more helpful as of now and **I have used:**

```
require(lattice)
xyplot(`Diameter(inches).Sep` ~ Treatment , merged.Sep.Dec.Mar, pch= 20)
```

**to generate the plot:**

[image]

However, **I want to add the scatter plot for "Diameter from Dec" next to the "Diameter of Sep" for each treatments with different color.** I am not able to find a workable example that I can use for my purpose so far.

Method with `lattice`, `ggplot2` or `base plot` or any other would be really helpful.

Thanks,

Comment: Your example data seems to have 4 columns but only 3 headers?

Comment: Oops bummer. I am going to remove that. Thanks. But, it really doesn't affect the intent of the question.

Comment: No, but it does make it difficult to answer when we try to recreate your data :)

Comment: Yeah, totally. That was mistake. Just fixed it. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Side-by-side plots with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249548/side-by-side-plots-with-ggplot2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(Month, Diameter, -Treatment) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Treatment, Diameter)) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = Month), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9))
```

[image]

You can adjust the amount of separation between the different coloured points by changing `width` inside `position_dodge`.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "Treatment   Diameter(inches).Sep    Diameter(inches).Dec
Aux_Drop    NA  NA
Aux_Spray    3.7    2
DMSO    NA  NA
Water   4.2 2
Aux_Drop    2.6 3
Aux_Spray    3.7    3
DMSO    4   2
Water   5.2 1
Aux_Drop    5.4 2
Aux_Spray    3.4    2
DMSO    4.8 2
Water   4.2 2
Aux_Drop    4.7 2
Aux_Spray    2.7    2
DMSO    3.4 2
Water   4.9 2", header = T)
```

Comment: This is totally good. Btw, how did you create new "data or variable" i.e "Month", "Diameter" ?

Comment: @everestial007 In `gather(Month, Diameter, -Treatment)`, we reshape data across all columns except `Treatment` from wide to long, and in doing so store column names in a new column `Month` and its values in column `Diameter`.

Comment: could you add the code to reshape the data. I tried using other examples but I can't seem to work it out.

Comment: @everestial007 `gather(Month, Diameter, -Treatment)` already reshapes the data from wide to long. It's just the one line.

Comment: Alrite, I got it. I really need to look into how this reshape works. The problem that has happened is that I have several other columns of data for other traits, and this seems to plot everything by treatment. For now, I will reduce the data only by months. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution. It uses `tidyr::gather` to put the two diameter types into one column. You can then facet on the values in that column. I hide the colour legend, since the categories are apparent from the axis labels.

Assuming the data frame is named `mydata`.

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>% 
  gather(Result, Value, -Treatment) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Result, Value)) + 
    geom_jitter(aes(color = Result), 
                width = 0.1) + 
    facet_wrap(~Treatment) +
    guides(color = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: @neifws : This not what I want. I want to have data for say (Aux_Drop) next to each other in the same plot

Comment: Not, exactly what I intended, but your answer is also helpful for another way of representing the data :)