# a graph with two lines, separating into different graphs based on one column values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe in this format, but with several hundred more rows:

```
dfex = data.frame(dot = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'), 
                  group = c('A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A2', 'A2', 'A2'), 
                  x1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), 
                  x2 = c(4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3), 
                  y = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6))
```

I want to create different graphs based on the value in `group`, so one graph will only have group A1 rows and the other graph only has group A2 rows.

On each graph, there should be two different lines for the x1-y pair and the x2-y pair. Preferably I could have the correlation for each of these lines listed as well.

I'm familiar with ggplot2, so using that would be great.

Here is an amazing paint drawing for a better idea of what I mean:
[image]

Comment: Are you just looking for facetting?

Comment: I'm not clear on what that is, but maybe. Looking through the documentation, I think that creates two graphs based on the `group` category? I'm not sure that will also get my two lines per graph. If you could provide an example of how facetting is used with my`exdf` that would be helpful!

Comment: You'll want to reshape your data to have all x values in one column instead of separate x1 and x2 columns. Then you can add `facet_wrap`. Several questions cover each step separately, and some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1249548/5325862) address both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @camille, it is better to reshape the data to long format before plotting.

```
library(tidyverse)

dfex %>%
  gather(key, value, -c(dot, group, y)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(value, y, color = key) + 
  geom_line() + 
  facet_wrap(.~group)
```

[image]

Comment: This almost works, but I want to display the points as well as the line. `geom_point()` doesn't seem to work after the `gather`

Comment: @Liquidity Do you mean ? `dfex %>%
  gather(key, value, -c(dot, group, y)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  aes(value, y, color = key) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(.~group)`

Comment: I guess I did! I didn't know the geom_point needed to go after geom_line()

Answer (score 2):

The below code will split into two parts. The facet_wrap will divide the graph into two columns on the group. I have created two lines because of the variables being stored in separate columns.

```
ggplot(dfex) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = x1, y = y, color = "blue")) +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = x2, y = y, color = "red")) +
  facet_wrap(. ~group)
```

Or additionally to gather the data into a more tidy format,

```
gather(dfex, "xVar", "x", 3:4) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, color = xVar)) +
  facet_wrap(. ~group)
```

Comment: Take a look at how `ggplot` is designed to work, though: you rarely want to repeat geoms that do basically the same thing, or hardcode values in your `aes` instead of mapping aesthetics like color to a variable. You can reshape the data to a long format more appropriate for `ggplot`

Comment: Agreed but was just doing it with the original dataset. Will edit the post to also gather the data