# How do I include muliple figures on a PowerPoint slide in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, powerpoint

I am generating a PowerPoint presentation with R-markdown. How do I include multiple figures or "contents" on a slide?

I have tried modifying the PowerPoint template to include three content blocks as following:
[image: img]
But I am unable to add content to the object on the bottom right.

````
---
title: "pp_test"
output: 
  powerpoint_presentation:
    reference_doc: pp_template3.pptx
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

# Slide with 3 contents

:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column}
Text
:::
::: {.column}
```{r pressure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="Caption"}
plot(pressure)
```
:::
::: {.column}
```{r cars, echo = TRUE}
summary(cars)
```
:::
::::::::::::::
````

I expected the "summary(cars)" section to be added beneath the plot on the slide, but it is simply excluded.

Comment: Can you pre-create multiple figures in R then add them to the powerpoint later? https://stackoverflow.com/q/1249548/786542

Answer (score 4):

I was unable to succeed using r-markdown, so I researched other packages and found "officer", which was able to produce the results I wanted.

It does not support tables that are not dataframes, so I was unable to add the "summary(cars)" part. But with two plots as examples, I was able to produce the result
[image: Result with officer]

Using the following code

```
library(officer)
library(magrittr)
library(ggplot2)
setwd(mydir)

my_plot <- ggplot(data=pressure) +
  geom_point(aes(temperature, pressure))
my_summary <- as.str(summary(cars))

my_pres <- 
  read_pptx("pp_template3.pptx") %>%
  add_slide(layout = "Two Content", master = "Office Theme") %>%
  ph_with_text(type = "title", index = 1, str = "The title") %>%
  ph_with_gg(type = "body", index = 1, value = my_plot) %>%
  ph_with_text(type = "body", index = 2, str = "Some text") %>%
  ph_with_gg(type = "body", index = 3, value = my_plot) %>%
  print(target = "test_pp_officer.pptx") %>%
  invisible()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Background

> I have tried modifying the PowerPoint template to include three content blocks as following:

According to [this RStudio Support article](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004672913-Rendering-PowerPoint-Presentations-with-the-RStudio-IDE), I don't think you're allowed to change the slide masters in the PPTX template because:

> The template should contain the following four layouts as its first four layouts [...]

It then specifically lists the slide master layouts as:

> 1. **Title**. Has placeholders for a title and a subtitle. Used for information in the YAML header.
> 2. **Title and Content**. Has placeholders for title and content. Used for headers at the [slide level](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004672913-Rendering-PowerPoint-Presentations-with-the-RStudio-IDE#structuring-the-presentation).
> 3. **Section Header**. Has a placeholder for a section header – content will not render on this layout. Used for headers above the [slide level](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004672913-Rendering-PowerPoint-Presentations-with-the-RStudio-IDE#structuring-the-presentation).
> 4. **Two Content**. Has placeholders for title and two content. Used for headers at the [slide level](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004672913-Rendering-PowerPoint-Presentations-with-the-RStudio-IDE#structuring-the-presentation) with content in [columns](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004672913-Rendering-PowerPoint-Presentations-with-the-RStudio-IDE#columns).

Your custom master seems to violate the "two content" format as you have 3 content blocks. (Not only that, but from my experimentation even changing the box sizes in the master slide of a template messes up how the content is inserted.) I think the:

```
:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column}

:::
::: {.column}

:::
::::::::::::::
```

Syntax only works for 2 columns, not 3 like you have.

## R Markdown solution for including multiple figures in one column of a 2-column slide in PowerPoint output

If you want to stay in an R Markdown workflow without using `officer`, a very easy way to include multiple `ggplot2` plots in a single image is to use the recent [`patchwork` package](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/index.html), and then add the combined plot chunk into one of the columns:

````markdown
---
output:
  powerpoint_presentation:
    slide_level: 2 # h1 makes a new section slide, h2 makes a new slide
    reference_doc: template.pptx
---

```{r setup, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
    echo = F,
    warning = F,
    message = F
)

library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)
```

## Define some plots

```{r, echo=TRUE}
p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(mpg, disp)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 1')

p2 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(gear, disp, group = gear)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 2')

p3 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_point(aes(hp, wt, colour = mpg)) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 3')

p4 <- ggplot(mtcars) + 
  geom_bar(aes(gear)) + 
  facet_wrap(~cyl) + 
  ggtitle('Plot 4')
```

## Plot text bullets in 1st column and 4 plots in 2nd column

::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column}
- here is some text 
- in the left column 
- to describe the plots 
- in the right column
:::
::: {.column}
```{r, fig.width=6, fig.height=4, fig.cap="This is the caption for the figure."}
# Adjust figure dimensions in chunk options
# use layout syntax form the 'patchwork' package
p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 # keeps square arrangement by default
```
:::
:::::::::
````