# multiple plots in one RStudio

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I am looking to plot the top 20 games in terms of their sales for 4 categories (EU, JP, NA and other) on the one plot.

I pulled the top 20 for each using the below code:

```
# creating a scatterplot of the top 20 in each category
top20NA <- head(sort(games$NA_Sales,decreasing=TRUE), n = 20)
top20EU <- head(sort(games$EU_Sales,decreasing=TRUE), n = 20)
top20JP <- head(sort(games$JP_Sales,decreasing=TRUE), n = 20)
top20other <- head(sort(games$Other_Sales,decreasing=TRUE), n = 20)
```

i then tried to run the below block but it just seems to run the last plot:

```
plot(top20NA, col ="Blue")
plot(top20EU, col = "Black")
plot(top20JP, col = "Yellow")
plot(top20other, col = "Green")
```

x axis should be ranking and y axis should be sales

any ideas? Thanks in advance

[image: plot]

Comment: Would probably easier with `ggplot2` https://stackoverflow.com/q/1249548/786542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can plot multiple scatterplots in the same window using the par() function.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(top20NA, col ="Blue", ylab="Sales", xlab="Ranking")
plot(top20EU, col = "Black", ylab="Sales", xlab="Ranking")
plot(top20JP, col = "Yellow", ylab="Sales", xlab="Ranking")
plot(top20other, col = "Green", ylab="Sales", xlab="Ranking")
```

If you want to plot all of your series on the same plot, you can use the lines() and points() functions.

```
plot(top20NA, ylim = c(0,15), col = "Blue", type = "b",
 ylab="Sales", xlab="Ranking")
points(top20EU, col = "Black")
lines(top20EU, col = "Black")
points(top20JP, col = "Yellow")
lines(top20JP, col = "Yellow")
points(top20other, col = "Green")
lines(top20other, col = "Green")
```

Admittedly, this is a bit clunky in base R, but it does get the job done.

Comment: Hi Jalind, i was hoping to create one plot with 4 different colours, this generates 4 different plots. Is it possible to merge them do you know?

Comment: Hi Gary. I've updated my answer to allow for plotting multiple series on the same plot.

Answer (score 0):

Having  a snippet of data would be really helpful, anyway I'd go for `dplyr` and `ggplot`:

1. Merge your data, have one row per game with 2 columns for *index* and *sales*.

```r
> library(dplyr)
> iris %>% 
+     select(Species, Petal.Length, Sepal.Length) %>% 
+     head()
  Species Petal.Length Sepal.Length
1  setosa          1.4          5.1
2  setosa          1.4          4.9
3  setosa          1.3          4.7
4  setosa          1.5          4.6
5  setosa          1.4          5.0
6  setosa          1.7          5.4
```

2. Now you can plot your scatterplot using `colour = yourvar` or `shape = yourvar` in the aesthethics to distinguish different games.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
iris %>% 
    select(Species, Petal.Length, Sepal.Length) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(Petal.Length, Sepal.Length, colour = Species, shape = Species)) + 
    geom_point()
```

Which will give you something like this:
[image]