# Plotting multiple diagrams on different scales in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot some diagrams beside each other (e.g. in columns) and write them to one png file. In `graphics::plot` it works with `layout(...)`, but how do I arrange diagrams in `ggplot2`?

Is there something I can do with facets?

Example:

```
require(cars)
require(data.table)
require(tidyr)

df <- as.data.table(mtcars)
df$obs <- seq_len(df[,.N])

df <- as.data.table(pivot_longer(data = df, names_to = "name", values_to = "val", cols = names(df[, !"obs"])))
df[, name := as.factor(name)]

library(ggplot2)
g <- ggplot(data = df)
g <- g + aes(x = df[, obs], y = df[, val])
g + facet_wrap(df[, name]) + geom_line()
```

It is not perfect. This gives me a matrix of diagrams for all properties of `mtcars`. But the y axis is always set to the maximum of the largest value of all properties.

I want the y axis to have the optimum range for each property.

Another thing is, how to plot different tables in the same file:

```
df1 <- as.data.table(mtcars)[, 1]
df1$obs <- seq_len(df1[,.N])
df2 <- as.data.table(mtcars)[, 2]
df2$obs <- seq_len(df2[,.N])

g1 <- ggplot(data = df1)
g1 <- g1 + aes(x = df1[, obs], y = df1[, mpg])
g1 + geom_line()

g2 <- ggplot(data = df2)
g2 <- g2 + aes(x = df2[, obs], y = df2[, cyl])
g2 + geom_line()
```

How can I arrange my plots? I don't want them to be plotted in the same diagram. They should have their own axes and titles.

Comment: R packages `patchwork` or `gridExtra` seem to be what you are looking for.
For `patchwork`, check for example this page: https://www.datanovia.com/en/blog/ggplot-multiple-plots-made-ridiculuous-simple-using-patchwork-r-package/

Comment: Installing files from non CRAN sources is not an option for me (company restrictions).

Comment: Both are CRAN sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just free your scale using `scales="free"` option.

```
g + facet_wrap(df[, name], scales="free") + geom_line()
```

[image]

For your second question, you may want to consult this answer: [Side-by-side plots with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1249548/6574038)