# How do I combine multiple plots in one graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need some help to combine four individual plots on a single page (single plot). I draw four different plots using the same codes but with different data groups. I need to draw all four plots on a single page.

```
library(ggpubr)
library(rstatix)
library(xlsx)
df<-read.xlsx("umar.xlsx", header = T, 1)
# Statistical test

######## Figure 1 ########
stat.test <- df %>%
  t_test(Moisture_content ~ substrate) %>%
  add_significance()
stat.test

# Box plots with p-values
bxp <- ggboxplot(df, x = "substrate", y = "Moisture_content", fill = "substrate", 
                 palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), width = 0.35)



stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "substrate")
bxp + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p = {p}") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.1)))+
  theme(
    aspect.ratio = 3
  )


######## Figure 2 ########
stat.test <- df %>%
  t_test(pH ~ substrate) %>%
  add_significance()
stat.test

# Box plots with p-values
bxp <- ggboxplot(df, x = "substrate", y = "pH", fill = "substrate", 
                 palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), width = 0.35)



stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "substrate")
bxp + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p = {p}") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.1)))+
  theme(
    aspect.ratio = 3
  )


######## Figure 3 ########
stat.test <- df %>%
  t_test(EC ~ substrate) %>%
  add_significance()
stat.test

# Box plots with p-values
bxp <- ggboxplot(df, x = "substrate", y = "EC", fill = "substrate", 
                 palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), width = 0.35)



stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "substrate")
bxp + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p = {p}") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.1)))+
  theme(
    aspect.ratio = 3
  )

######## Figure 4 ########
stat.test <- df %>%
  t_test(Moisture_content ~ substrate) %>%
  add_significance()
stat.test

# Box plots with p-values
bxp <- ggboxplot(df, x = "substrate", y = "Moisture_content", fill = "substrate", 
                 palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"), width = 0.35)



stat.test <- stat.test %>% add_xy_position(x = "substrate")
bxp + 
  stat_pvalue_manual(stat.test, label = "p = {p}") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0.05, 0.1)))+
  theme(
    aspect.ratio = 3
  )
```

Comment: With `ggpubr::ggarrange`?

Comment: Hi @Vincent Guillemot  thanks for the comments. Could you please provide some  more details? 
Best regards,

Comment: Without your data, it's difficult to help. There are two options -- you can make different plots and then arrange them on a page using the code in the `ggpubr` or `cowplot` libraries as @VincentGuillemot suggests, or you can rehape your data to long format and use `facet_wrap()` or `facet_grid()` to plot the different outcomes in a single plot.

Comment: Here is my data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1r1SeqBTWwve1MBqKHg7Kg1h6ey09DVP4/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=102539758905103985682&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Side-by-side plots with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249548/side-by-side-plots-with-ggplot2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to combine multiple ggplot-based plots is with the *patchwork* package:

```r
library(patchwork)
plot1 + plot2 + plot3 + plot4
```

Comment: Great rec, thanks! I was previously using `cowplot::plot_grid()` and couldn't for the life of me figure out why it was stretching my x-axis labels. This worked great!

Answer (score 5):

Using ggarrange from ggpubr, like this:
library(ggplot2)

```
plot_1 <- your_ggplot_code
plot_2 <- your_ggplot_code

library(ggpubr)

#See ?ggarrange

combined_plot <- ggarrange(plot_1,
                           plot_2,
                           nrow = 2,
                           ncol = 1) #nrow & ncol depend on how you want to 
                                     #organize your plots
```

Good luck!