# display different object types on a power point slide using RMarkdown

Tags: r, plotly, r-markdown, powerpoint, flextable

I want to save different objects on a powerpoint slide and generate a deck using RMarkdown.

I found [Side-by-side plots with ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249548/side-by-side-plots-with-ggplot2) to display two `ggplot`, but it did not work for `plotly` images.

My use case would like to combine

- up to 3 flextables
- plotly image
- text box with specific location

our current solution is to save each as images and write them to a ppt, but this is not optimal.

My sample `rmd` is here:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: powerpoint_presentation
date: "2023-01-13"
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Slide with R Output

```{r echo = FALSE}
df = data.frame(col1="brocolli", col2 = "and spinach and kale and peas and lettuce")
df %>%
  flextable() %>%
  fontsize(part = "all", size = 7) %>%
  width(2,5)
```

## 
```{r echo = FALSE}
df = data.frame(col1="Apples", col2 = "and bananas and oranges and pears and pinapple")
df %>%
  flextable() %>%
  fontsize(part = "all", size = 7) %>%
  width(2,5)
```

## Slide with Plot

```{r pressure}

trace_0 <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
trace_1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
trace_2 <- rnorm(100, mean = -5)
x <- c(1:100)

data <- data.frame(x, trace_0, trace_1, trace_2)

fig <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~trace_0, name = 'trace 0', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_1, name = 'trace 1', mode = 'lines+markers') 
fig <- fig %>% add_trace(y = ~trace_2, name = 'trace 2', mode = 'markers')

fig
```

```{r}

df = data.frame(matrix(round(rnorm(150),2), ncol = 10))
df %>%
  flextable() %>%
  fontsize(part = "all", size = 7)
```
````

result after I save each table/plot as png and save into single ppt slide is here (ignore the `text in red`, just for clarity where each chunk placed and where textbox would be added)

[image]

Are there any suggestions on if it is possible to include all the objects on a single slide?

Comment: This question is pretty broad. Can you make an example of the type of markdown you have? Otherwise we're just guessing

Comment: updated with example for clarity